# Use the approximation of $\,f(x)=\ln(1+x)\,$ at $\,x_0=0\,$ to estimate $\,\ln(15)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I've been trying to solve an exercise from my textbook which goes as following.
For the function $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$
a) compute the Taylor's approximation at $x_0 = 0$
b) use this approximation to estimate $\ln 15$

The confusing part of the exercise for me is the point b) 
How do I exactly use the approximation at $x_0 = 0$ to approximate $\ln (15)$?
$$f(x)= \ln(1+x)$$
$$f(x)\approx x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^4$$ This is the approximation at $x_0=0$ 
 To my understanding to approximate $\ln 15$ we need to choose a point which is close to $x=15$ as our $x_0$ in order to approximate the value of $\ln15$. So my question is how do I exactly use this formula of $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ at $x_0=0$ for   $\ln(15)$?

Comment: Not sure where this taylor series converges at all, but the first step is to consider $$\ln(15)=\ln(3)+\ln(5)$$

Comment: It seems to me that their point is for you to explore the fact that the radius of convergence of that series is just 1 by working with the series far outside its radius of convergence.

Comment: How about taking x=-1/16 and x=-1/2 and combining the results?

Comment: @AnneBauval Pertaining to this exercise? Not really I'm afraid.

Comment: @Peter I will try that, thank you.

Comment: @Ian That could be, however the answer to point b) is 2,708

Comment: I think that they want you to extend the radius of convergence which then will give you the taylor series for ln(15) too. I think the approximation is more that you then just calculate the first few parts of the taylor-series for ln(15). We had a similar exercise back in Highschool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor polynomial $T(x)$ that you’re using to approximate $f(x)$ around zero can not be used to approximate $f$ around $14$. Only $x$ values close to zero would work.

Please check the picture showing the two functions around zero: in red is $f(x)$ and in blue is $T(x)$. It was obtained from [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/owprwkjpti)

[image: red is f, blue is Taylor approximation of f]

$$\ln \left ( \frac{15}{e^3}\right )=\underbrace{\ln 15-3}_{\approx -0.2919}=-\ln \left ( \frac{e^3}{15}\right )=-\ln \left ( 1+\frac{e^3-15}{15}\right )\approx -T \left ( \frac{e^3-15}{15}\right )\approx -0.2912$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider that
$$\log 15=\log(16-1)=\log\left(16\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)\right)=\log 16 +\log\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right) $$
Since $-1/16$ is "small", you can apply the formula you've found for $x_0=0$.

Apply the same reasoning to $\log 16$, keeping in mind that:
$$\log 16 =4\log 2$$
To find $\log 2$, note that $-\log 2=\log (1-1/2)$.

Answer (score 3):

You have$$-\log(15)=\log\left(\frac1{15}\right)=\log\left(\frac13\right)+\log\left(\frac15\right).$$Now,$$\log\left(\frac13\right)=\log\left(1-\frac23\right)\approx\sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\left(-\frac23\right)^k\approx-1.09587$$and$$\log\left(\frac15\right)=\log\left(1-\frac45\right)\approx\sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\left(-\frac45\right)^k\approx-1.57887.$$So, $\log(15)\approx2.67474$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$f(x) = \ln \left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right)= \ln(1-x) - \ln(1+x)$$
If we substitute the series for $\ln(1+x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$ (which is just the series for $\ln(1+x)$ with $x$ replaced by $-x$) up to $x^4$ in the above, we find
$$f(x) \approx -2 \left( \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{4} x^4 \right)$$
Now set $x = 14/16$, so $\frac{1-x}{1+x} = 1/15$. This results in
$$f(14/16)=\ln(1/15) \approx -2.7036$$
so
$$\ln(15) \approx 2.7036$$

Answer (score 0):

With $x=\frac 18$, you find an approximation $a$ for $2\ln 3-3\ln2$.
With $x=\frac3{125}$, you find an approximation $b$ for $7\ln2-3\ln5$.
With $x=\frac1{14}$, you find an approximation for $\ln3+\ln5-\ln2-\ln7$.
With $x=\frac1{49}$, you find an approximation for $\ln 2+2\ln5-2\ln7$.
That’s four equations for the four unknowns $\ln 2, \ln3,\ln5,\ln7$.
Solve and compute $\ln3+\ln5$.

All this is based on $2^3\approx3^2$, $2^7\approx5^3$, etc.
The main problem is that you need to keep track of error estimates, and that the largest error occurs with the largest $x$ (that is, $\frac18$).
It may be better to replace $2^3\approx3^2$ with $15^2\approx2^57$.